# How use my compiled android instant app project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I have build a full instant app project in Android Studio 3.5. I can easily run my instant app project on emulator in a debug mod and everything is working correctly.

instant app project on emulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJVbI.jpg (screenshot)

So I compiled this project and Android Studio create 2 file for me.

Output files:

- instant-app.json
- instantapp-release.zip

my question: How use from this two files for publish to my users, in fact I need my user open https://www.d.com/ and my instant app opened such as my debug mod run on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to upload your zip file to *Release management > Android Instant Apps* section. 
Check out [Distribute your instant experience](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861?hl=en) guide for more details about instant app publishing process. 
Note: Before publishing your instant app, you must upload an APK of your installed app (on the App releases page).

Comment: it is very useful for me but Is it possible without Google Play? in fact I need just with open a link so open my instant app